# Problemas para consumir Web service SOAP https

Tags: php, laravel, soap, soapui

Tengo un WS, pero cuando invoco a uno de sus métodos me sale un mensaje `message:protected =>Forbiden`, pero cuando lo testeo el WS con la app SOAP UI si puedo acceder a sus métodos y realizo pruebas me retorna los valores que corresponde.

Segun las especificaciones del servicio por ejemplo para acceder al metodo 'auntetica', hay que pasarle 3 parametros y ya debería funcionar.
el servicio esta en protocolo https, tengo que agregarle en algun lado algun certificado?

```
   try {

$servicio="https://myws.svc?wsdl";

$parametros=array(
    'CODE' => 'ttt',
    'COD' => 'rrr',
    'CODI' => 'aaaaa'
);
$client = new SoapClient($servicio);
$result = $client->autentifica($parametros);
  var_dump($result);
 } catch ( SoapFault $e ) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: tengo el mismo problema si pudiste solucionarlo seria d egran ayuda Saludos

Comment: Hola Henry disculpa por no haber contestado, si solucione haber si aun tienes el inconveniente me escribes. Saludos